# Sublime text 3 OSX: After multi select, can I tab focus between cursors?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I find the *CMD + D very useful

But is there a way to table the cusor between the selections?

For instance if I have five cursors all after `item-` :

```
<li class="item-">
<li class="item-">
<li class="item-">
<li class="item-">
<li class="item-">
```

can I "tab" through cursors so I can just type `(tab)rap(tab)don(tab)mic(tab)leo(tab)splinter`
and end up with:

```
<li class="item-raph">
<li class="item-don">
<li class="item-mic">
<li class="item-leo">
<li class="item-splinter">
```

**It takes what is already selected, and then selects the next text that matches your original selection*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
alt+super+g (Mac OSX)
Ctrl+F3 (Windows)
```

However this is replacing the `Ctrl+D` operation. So just select the first instance of `item-` then

- type: "raph"
- `alt+super+g` / `Ctrl+F3`
- type: "don"
- `alt+super+g` / `Ctrl+F3`
- ...